# Как поместить данные переменной audio?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Всем привет.

Вопрос состоит в следующем: есть База Данных с таблицей music, в которой хранятся данные (artist, title, filename,...). Есть страничка music.aspx(music.aspx.cs). Теперь мне всё это надо вывести на страничке, в виде плеера. В файле music.aspx.cs делаем выборку данных:

```
var entity = new DataBaseEntity();
var audio = entity.audio;
```

Теперь, надо вывести содержимое audio на страничке music.aspx

Надо сделать примерно что-то типа такого (ASP.NET Entity Framework):

```
<% foreach(track in audio) //Как СЮДА поместить данные переменной audio
{ %>
<div>
    <% audio.artist + " " + audio.title ...  %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Может не совсем корректно написан код,... но суть не в этом. )

Comment: Неужели никто не знает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

почитайте про Repeater'ы

Comment: Вот как раз уже разобрался. Но всё равно спасибо. )